# Plotting values of the bar above it on the graph. Can someone guide me through how to do this? Thanks

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(ItemTrack, columns=['Items Taken'])
df.insert(1, "Expenditure", ExpenseTrack, True)
df['Items Taken'] = df['Items Taken'].str.capitalize()
print(df)
x = df['Items Taken']
y = df['Expenditure']
plt.bar(x, y)
plt.xticks(rotation=30, color='green')
plt.yticks(rotation=30, color='red')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please add sample data (for ItemTrack, I guess), and a clear explanation of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Item Track contains all the list of the items

Comment: While the Expense Track contains how much you bought it for

Comment: Item Track = [Fish, Chip]
Expense Track = [5, 7]
like that

Comment: Please edit the question, and include code and data that would allow someone to easily reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Items Taken': [f'Item {i}' for i in range(5)],
    'Expenditure' : [i * 100 for i in range(5)]
})
df['Items Taken'] = df['Items Taken'].str.capitalize()
x = df['Items Taken']
y = df['Expenditure']
plt.bar(x, y)
plt.xticks(rotation=30, color='green')
plt.yticks(rotation=30, color='red')
for i, v in enumerate(y):
    plt.text(i, v, str(v), color='red', ha='center', fontweight='bold')
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ax.text()](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html) and loop over the coordinates.

Set the transform keyword argument to ax.transData so the that the coordinates you pass correspond with the datarange in you axis. alternatively you can use ax.transAxes or fig.transFigure.

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

ax.bar(x, y)

# assuming that the you want the y value above the bar
offset_y = 2 # offset to place the text above the bar. Chosen number here is arbitrary 

for i range(x):
    ax.text(i, y[i]+offset_y, y[i], 
            va='center',
            ha='center',
            transform=ax.transData
    )

ax.set_xticks(rotation=30, color='green')
ax.set_yticks(rotation=30, color='red')

plt.show()
```